# How can I see running ports on Windows 11?

Tags: port, netstat, windows-11

I need to see port:8080 is running or not. And I tried:
`netstat -a -b`

and it returned error message "The requested operation requires elevation."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a native GUI for Windows:

- Start menu → All Programs → Accessories → System Tools → Resource
  Monitor
- or run resmon.exe,
- or from TaskManager → Performance tab.

You can see details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23718720/5736794).